# Force injected javascript asset via ajax to re-execute, on multiple injections

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, webpack

I have a peculiar issue. I have a widget loader, that is responsible for loading a specific javascript asset:

```
$.ajax("cdn.example.com/widget.js", {
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: false
}).then(function() {
  console.log(window.widgetRenderTime);
})
```

When I get to a particular point in the web-app, I load the widget using the code above.  Here is what the widget looks like:

```
const timestamp = "hi" + new Date().getTime();

window.widgetRenderTime = timestamp;
```

The above code is an illustration of `widget.js`.  When I get to the point where the widget is downloaded and injected into the page, everything works great.

Now, if I navigate away from the widget, then back to the point where the widget gets invoked *again*, the code does not re-execute, because the source has already been evaluated in the page.  Therefore, the "widgetRenderTime", is actually the render time of the first time the widget was invoked.

Is there a way to remove, and re-execute a javascript asset injected into the webpage?  I have cache busting on, so a new asset shows up in the sources tab of Chrome, but it doesn't actually execute.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you show where that ajax call is executed?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  You can imagine it gets called when you push a specific button. It will load the external js asset. If I push the button a second time, the external asset has been loaded already and won't re evaluate the code in that file

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I made a jsfiddle about your problem and the issues seems to be, that `timestamp` has already been defined and thus error's out: https://jsfiddle.net/deiga/d8h1d6j2/8/

The proper way to do it would be to namespace your variables so you wouldn't pollute the global namespace